# Zeppelin [0.7.2]: NullPointerException on executing paragraph from a new Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Whenever I create a new notebook and run a paragraph, I get the NullPointerException error. If I run from an existing notebook then no problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:391)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:380)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:828)
```

I workaround the problem by restarting the Zeppelin daemon. Saw other instances of this error but resolution given was it is fixed in 0.7.2 version which is what I am using. Anybody else facing the same problem? Have I missed something in configuration? Thanks.

Comment: What do you see in the zeppelin logs ?

Comment: Same as the above error message. Basically it is not able to bind to the Spark interpreter. Restarting Zeppelin daemon works. But I can't be the only guy who is facing such a problem. Thanks.

Comment: any solution? im facing the same

Comment: None yet. I restart manually. :(

Comment: for me even after zeppekin restart it is same.. :( any idea?

Comment: Had the same problem and solved it by set ```spark.executor.cores```, ```spark.executor.instances```, ```spark.executor.memory``` in the interpreter settings down.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was resolved after setting useHiveContext to false in Spark interpreter settings.

> zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext => false